# I was asked to train new hire on my job - is this eventual replacement?

Tags: work-environment, conflict

Boss hired a senior IT team member (senior to me and others) with same but better skill set and I am to train them on my job (other devs are not asked to even though they have the skills to) but I do have the experience and have proven myself over the years so I understand that naturally I am the one to train him on my job for him to get familiar to his job but in an expanded role capacity. The company has been through layoffs in the past and I am concerned my job as well.

Over the years I have delivered consistently and praised by management outside of team, so I am not “low hanging fruit” but I can’t help feeling persona non grata.  And to be clear I am not vying for the role, I’m lucky if it doesn’t impact my job.

What should I do and should I be concerned or is this a normal occurrence?

I know that the normal answer is to update my resume, but I’m looking for insight and other options I need to take into consideration and what consequences will these choices have?
If ultimately the situation doesn’t look good to you then I respect that and tell me as it is - don’t hold back.

Comment: Paranoia is a terrible drug.

Answer (score 6):

We don't know, we cannot say.

The only thing you should be focusing on is - do your job. If your boss asked you to train the new engineer, do that. There can be many things going on - they may be thinking of promoting you with a larger / different set of responsibilities, or they might be thinking of firing you, and for most part, neither of them can be changed by "thinking" about it by you.

Let it be, and focus on getting your job done.

---

P.S - if some positive perspective makes you feel better, here are some of the possibilities:

- They're looking to promote you with a different roles and responsibilities. So, they need a substitute for you.
- Maybe they are a substitute for your manager.
- They're looking to start a new project / assignment similar to the one you're taking care of, that's why you are asked to train the new team members.
- They have some other assignment lined up for you, where they want you to shift focus from your current responsibilities and take care of something else - a similar training might be lined up for you also (by someone else).
- They think that you're the best person to impart the training in general, that's why you've been asked. This is not directly related to you

so on on so forth.

Comment: Also, "(senior to me and others) with same but better skill set" usually translates to more expensive. It's unlikely that such a person would simply replace OP, since they claim that management is satisfied with their performance.

Comment: This answer does not address that if the boss is looking for replacement he needs to see the signs and start putting out resume asap

Answer (score 2):

> What should I do and should I be concerned or is this a normal occurrence?

Onboarding and training of new team members is usually a normal part of working in IT. I wouldn't be concerned unless your employer has a pattern of hiring new people in order to replace their existing employees.

With regards to the risk to your own job, *based on what you've said*, this appears to be low. You say you've done your work well and are praised for it, so you're not being removed for incompetence (also in that case you wouldn't be training your replacement). The new hire is more senior than you, so presumably they would be more expensive in the long term, and that makes a cost saving motivation unlikely. More likely, this is an attempt to increase the size of the team you're on, possibly with an eye to more upcoming work.

So, what should you do? You should do your best to deliver good training to your new coworker. Not only will this continue to show off your strengths and skills to your manager, but it also builds a useful skill for the future, that of sharing your skills with other people. If you do wind up moving jobs, for whatever reason, having some experience training a peer is going to make you a more attractive candidate.

Answer (score 1):

Even if this is a potential replacement for you, if you don't do a proper job at training them you're just making your own upcoming performance review that much worse for yourself, increasing your chances of losing your job.

Who knows, this might be a replacement for you in your current job because you're slated to be promoted. If you now do a bad job training them you're ruining your chances at that promotion...